# Limit of a series of difference quotients minus derivatives of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}_+$ be real positive numbers with and $\frac{1}{2}<a<1$ and let $I=[0,b]$ be a closed real interval

Let $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: f_n(x) : I \to \mathbb{R}$ be the sequence of functions with 
$$
f_n(x)
=
{
\dfrac{n}{(2n-1)^{a+x}}
-
\dfrac{n}{(2n)^{a+x}}
}
$$
and let $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: g_n(x) : I \to \mathbb{R}$ be the sequence of functions with 
$$
g_n(x)
=
\dfrac
{d}{dx}
f_n(x)
=
\dfrac{n \cdot \ln(2n)}{(2n)^{a+x}}
-
\dfrac{n \cdot \ln(2n-1)}{(2n-1)^{a+x}}
$$
Let $h : I \to \mathbb{R}$ be the funtion
$$
h(x)=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty
\left|
\dfrac{f_n(x)-f_n(0)}{x}
-
g_n(0)
\right|^2
$$
My question is if it is true that
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+}
h(x)=0
$$
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you are asking is that we are to sum the squares of the difference between the actual rate of how much a function rises minus the first derivative rate for n ranging $(1,\infty)$. Since the difference between $x=0^+$ and $x=0$ does not depend upon $n$, I'd say that the limit is $0$. But if you give some dependence of $h=0^+-0$ on $n$, the answer may change.

By taylor expansion:$$f_n(h)=f_n(0)+\frac h{1!}g_n(0)+\frac{h^2}{2!}f_n^{''}(0)+\frac{h^3}{3!}f_n^{'''}(0)+...\infty$$
or
$$\frac{f_n(h)-f_n(0)}{h}-g_n(0)=\frac{h}{2!}f_n^{''}(0)+\frac{h^2}{3!}f_n^{'''}(0)+...\infty$$ 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\lim_{h\to 0}\Bigg|\frac{h}{2!}f_n^{''}(0)+\frac{h^2}{3!}f_n^{'''}(0)+...\infty\Bigg|^2=\Bigg|-\frac{h}{2!}\frac{\ln^2(2)}{2^{a+h}}+\frac{h^2}{3!}\frac{\ln^3(2)}{2^{a+h}}...\infty\Bigg|^2+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\lim_{h\to 0}\Bigg|\frac{h}{2!}f_n^{''}(0)+\frac{h^2}{3!}f_n^{'''}(0)+...\infty\Bigg|^2=h^2\times i(n)$$

where $i(n)$ is some function depending on the magnitude of $n$ and may be however big but limit ends up at $0$ because $h$ can be made independently smaller than anything.